# Store multiple data sets from stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

This is how I store dataset in a table from a procedure that returns a single dataset.

```
 CREATE TABLE #TEMP (amount DECIMAL(18, 2), extra VARCHAR(50))  

 INSERT INTO #TEMP (extra, amount)
     EXEC sp_proc @para1, @para2, @para3
```

Now can I store dataset from procedures that return two or more tables. If possible how can I do that?

I don't intend to create temporary global tables as I would have to alter multiple procedures. Can I do so without altering the procedure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now Can i store dataset from procedures that return two or more tables. If possible how can i do that?

No, is not possible, at least not directly. One of the many limitations of `INSERT ... EXEC`. I recommend you modify the stored procedure to be split into individual separate stored procedures, each returning its own result set.

Indirectly you can do it by switching control outside of T-SQL, eg. by runing it via a SQLCLR procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You **don't store** multiple table result from SP in other tables.
You have to create separate SP for that